# Android getLastLocation always returns null

Tags: android, android-service, google-play-services, android-location, google-api-client

Hi there so today i was going to implement locations into my Android application but hit an unusual problem that i cant understand.

**The problem**

I started by looking at Googles official documents for getting the last known location and implemented it without success. I then took a look at the sample application provided and copied the exact code into my own application but this also failed. The application never produces any error and works exactly as it is supposed to but i'm simply not getting a location.

In the code below *mLastLocation* is always null in the application i am creating but works perfectly in the one google made. Note that this exact code is used by both me and google.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

/**
 * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Represents a geographical location.
 */
protected Location mLastLocation;

protected String mLatitudeLabel;
protected String mLongitudeLabel;
protected TextView mLatitudeText;
protected TextView mLongitudeText;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
    mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
    mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
    mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));

    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,
                mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel,
                mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
    // onConnectionFailed.
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
    // attempt to re-establish the connection.
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

}

**What i have done so far**

1. Made sure GPS & Wi-Fi is turned on as suggested in other threads. (Not working)
2. Started Google Maps to force a location as suggested in other threads. (Not working)
3. Downloaded the github [repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) and copied the core files into new project. (Not working)

After some hours of frustration i created a completely new project from scratch and tried to duplicate the official sample as much as possible but it still didn't work. So now i tried to run the sample code from Google directly after downloading it and of course that works like a charm but i don't understand why.
I also spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out why the git repo application works and why my own duplication of it dosen't even if all the code is exactly the same.

**What i need help with**

There seems to be no error in the code itself since the code works in the sample repo application and it is not producing any errors. I need someone to tell me what i'm missing!

To help you i setup a github repo with my two Android Studio projects. The project that dosen't work is called *BasicLocationSampleOwn* and the one that works is called *BasicLocationSample*.

You can download the repo here: https://github.com/CarlOhlsson/getLastLocationProblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by downgrading from API 23 to 22. Android 6.0 apparently doesn't produce any error message when permissions fail. I needed to request permission from the user on top of the permissions in the manifest file.

Android 6.0 permission information found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)